# Are there infinitely many numbers $X$ so that both $X+1$ and $\frac{X}{2}+1$ are squares?

Tags: sequences-and-series, programming

My grandad gave me a challenge and, like any non-cheating child, I wrote a program to solve it for me

It goes like this: $48$ is a peculiar number, because

- $48+1$ is square, and
- $\frac{48}{2}+1$ is square.

Find the next $3$ smallest examples of numbers $X$ that follow both of those rules.

- $X+1$ is square
- $\frac{X}{2}+1$ is square.

I wrote some code and ran it and got quite a few large examples, even so high as $16$ digits.

But then, after a while, I stopped finding new numbers. It is likely that my computer/my coding skills just can't take it high enough in a small time frame, but my math brain is itching.

Will this stop or will this pattern go on forever.

Why?

Comment: I think you meant _infinitely many_ numbers.

Comment: see my comment, following lulu's answer.

Comment: I edited your question so the title conveys better information about your question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=2n$.  Then we are told that $n=m^2-1$ and $2n=M^2-1$ for suitable  natural numbers $m,M$.  It follows that $$2m^2-2=M^2-1\implies 2m^2=M^2+1$$ or $$\boxed { M^2-2m^2=-1}$$

This is one instance of the classical [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).  And the solution is well documented online.

Comment: The _negative_ Pell's equation.

Comment: With respect to lulu's answer, **all** solutions are given by $P_n,Q_n = \left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^n ~: ~n$ must be an **odd** positive integer.  For example, $\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^3 = 7 + 5\sqrt{2}$, which leads to $7^2 - 2(5)^2 = -1.$

Comment: See also chapter 1 of [this pdf](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf).  See also [this pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).

Comment: Re my first comment, I intended that the solution of $P_n,Q_n$ is generated by $\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^n = P_n + Q_n\sqrt{2}, ~: ~n~$ must be an odd positive integer.